# GooglePlay Developer Console and Alpha Testing

Tags: android, google-play

I wanted to ask, if the following is possible in anyway ?
I have an app that is buggy since the last update and it is released in production in google play. 
I would like to disable the app for production and test the app throuth Alpha - Test.
I can't manage to do this. If I do not publish an app in production phase it is not possible to see the alpha-test version. If I wan't to test the alpha version I have to publish the production version, but this version is buggy !!

Isn't it possible to disable the productionphase and test through alpha - test until finished and then publish to production ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish the app as a Test application, visible only to a limited audience (In this case only to You) to test. Google has listed an elaborate procedure for this [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

Be sure to

1. Register test account(s) in the developer console.
2. Configure this test account on this device while testing (This is needed if your app has in-app purchases).

Comment: I added tester group and when i insert to "manage list of tester" , under the title : Testers opting in i get : 
Your app can only be used by your testers when it is published to Google Play. If your app has no production APK then it will only be visible to Alpha and Beta testers. The link that your testers can use to opt-in will be displayed here when you have published your app.

What is mean? how can i publish it but only for tester?

the status in alpa testing now is : 
STATUS : Draft in Prod